# jQuery center div in visible area of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<div>` that I am trying to vertically center in the visible area of its parent `<div>`.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd1jC.gif) is an image exemplifying what I am trying to accomplish.  The child `<div>` is represented by the white circle, the parent `<div>` is the grey rectangle and the white rectangle is the browser's viewport.

The issue that I'm having is with writing the formula for positioning the child `<div>` when the browser scrolls or is resized.  For any sized child or parent `<div>`.

[image: Center div in visible area of parent examples]

```
var scrollListener = function(){
    var child = $('.child'),        // child element
    w=$(window).height,             // window height
    s=$(window).scrollTop(),        // window scrollTop position
    t=child.parent().offset().top,  // parent position in window
    h=child.parent().height(),      // parent height
    p=(w+s-t),                      // initial position
    v=0;                            // final value for child position

    if( t<s ){
       // top of parent is beyond viewport
       if( p<h ){
          // bottom of parent is also beyond viewport
          v = (w/2)+s-t;
       }else{
          // ??? - not working
          // bottom of parent is within viewport
          v = ((h-p)/2)+s-t;
       }
    }else{
       v = p/2;
    }
    child.css("top",v);
};

$(window).on("scroll resize",scrollListener);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzbyy7dw/4/)**

Comment: what is the question/problem?

Comment: Where do you call scrollListener

Comment: Make a working fiddle or something, there is a lot going on and if you leave it to us we will come up with all different sorts of answers. Right now the question is too broad.

Comment: Here is fiddle I just made [https://jsfiddle.net/uzbyy7dw/](https://jsfiddle.net/uzbyy7dw/)

Comment: `position: relative`, `margin: auto` for `.child` centers the black box. Is that what you are after?

Comment: @RST that will center the child within the parent, but the center might be outside of the viewport.  I'm trying to center the child in the area of the parent that is visible. Here is an updated fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/uzbyy7dw/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/uzbyy7dw/2/)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to do. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: Does this image help clarify? [http://i.stack.imgur.com/vd1jC.gif](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vd1jC.gif)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution, a working example can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/uzbyy7dw/6/.

Nearly all my original calculating was scrapped.  My new approach was to determine whether the top edge of the parent `<div>` was outside the browser's viewport and then calculate the vertical center position for the child `<div>` based on whether the parent's bottom edge was outside the viewport.

Please note that the child `<div>` is has an absolute position within the parent `<div>`

```js
(function($){
var scrollListener = function(){
    $('.child').each(function(){
    var child = $(this),            // child div element
    w=$(window).height(),           // window height
    s=$(window).scrollTop(),        // window scrollTop position
    t=child.parent().offset().top,  // parent top edge
    h=child.parent().height(),      // parent height
    r=(w+s-t),                      // parent's initial visible area
    // parent's bottom edge in relation to the viewport
    // calculated by the parent's height minus it's initial visible area
    b=h-r,                          
    v=0;                            // final value for child position
    if( t<s ){
       /*
       The amount scrolled is greater than the parent's offset
       thus, the parent's top edge is outside the viewport
       */
       if( 0 < b ){
            /*
            When the parent's bottom edge is greater than 0 then
            it's bottom edge is below the bottom of the viewport
            
            Since both the top and bottom edge exceed the viewport 
            some middle section of the parent is spanning the
            full height of the viewport.  The child's position will be
            in the middle of viewport, but offset by the amount
            scrolled minus the parent's top offset
            */
            v = (w/2)+s-t;
       }else{
            /*
            The parent's top edge is outside the viewport, but the
            bottom edge is within the viewport
            
            Calculate the middle position by taking the amount scrolled
            minus the parent's offset and the parent's height, which
            will get the remaining visible area of the parent div, then
            divide by two to get the middle
            */
            v = (s-t+h)/2;
       }
    }else{
        /*
        The parent's top edge is greater than the amount scrolled
        thus, the parent top edge has not exceeded the viewport
        */
     if( 0 < b ){
           /*
            When the parent's bottom edge is greater than 0 then
            it is below the bottom of the viewport
            
            Since the parent's top edge has not exceeded the viewport
            and bottom edge HAS exceed the viewport, use the parent's
            initial position determined by adding the window's height
            and the amount scrolled then subtract the parent's offset.
            
            Divide this position by two to get the middle of the
            parent's visible area, unless the parent's top edge is
            below the viewport's bottom edge then the parent is out of
            view and the child will be too
            */
            v = r/2;
        }else{
           /*
            Both the top and bottom edges of the parent div are within
            the viewport.  Vertically center the child div within the
            parent by dividing the parent's height by 2 to get its
            middle
            */
            v = h/2;
      }
    }
    
    child.css("top",v);
    });
};

$(window).on("scroll resize",scrollListener);
scrollListener();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
html,body { background:white; height:100%; }
body{ margin-top:140%; }
.middle-line {
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:100;
  border-top:1px solid #2495ec;
}
.parent1, .parent2 {
  float:left;
  width:30%;
  margin-left:10px;
  position:relative;
}

.parent1 {
  background:#ccc;
  height:120%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  }
.parent2 {
  background:#aaa;
  height:50%;
}
.child {
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.other-stuff{
  height:800px;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent1">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="other-stuff"></div>
<div class="middle-line"></div>
```

Comment: "I figured out the solution" — what _**is**_ the solution?  Answering your own question is fine, but I'm not about to `diff` the files to figure out what the problem was, what you changed, and why.

Comment: @StephenP -- the problem was entirely in how the calculations were made.  I have updated my answer adding more detail to the js comments.